# Open a URL based on search query without php "?q=(myTerm)" and instead with a simple "/(myTerm)"

Tags: jquery, forms, tumblr

This is driving me up the wall. I obviously don't understand soemthing pretty fundamental, I'm hoping someone can shed light on the matter.

```
        <form action="/tagged" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>
```

[On this page](http://syndex.me) gives me http://syndex.me/tagged?q=yellow
But if I change `/tagged` to `/search` (the default state for tumblr search form) it actually does the right thing and gives a url to the effect of http://syndex.me/search/yellow.

All this just because, tumblrs search is actually broken. That's right. A company valued at $800 million does not have a viable search feature. The thing is if you go to http://syndex.me/tagged/yellow It actually *works!*. SO I'm just trying to hack the service and switch `/search` to `tagged`. Pretty mental.

I'm happy to hack that any way possible... jQuery?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Attach an event handler to the `submit` event which redirects the user to the URL that works? Not particularly clean, mind.

Comment: But why am i getting "?q=" on "tagged" and "/" on "search"? It just doesnt make sense to me. Is this because of the two pages being different?

Comment: Seems like there are [solutions](http://yeahitsray.tumblr.com/post/6313603731) [about](http://www.google.ch/search&q=tumblr+tag+search+field).

Comment: I'd agree with @Alex. Apparently, tumblr has a redirect on /search but not on /tagged. I'd hack the search form and update the URL to submit the correct url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parts of your page are the core behind the search function:

**JavaScript:**

```
function handleThis(formElm){
    window.location="http://syndex.me/tagged/"+formElm.q.value+"";
    return false;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="return handleThis(this)" >
    <input type="text" name="q" value=""/>
</form>
```

An event listener is bound to your form, using `onsubmit="return handleThis(this)"`.

- **`onsubmit`** is triggered when the user presses enter, or hits the Search button.
- Inside the `onsubmit` attribute (aka event handler), you notice **`return handleThis(this)`**. This function (which is defined at the same page; look ahead) is called with the `this` keyword as first argument. `this` from within the context of an event handler refers to the event listener's owner element, in this case `<form>`.
  In `handleThis(formElm)`, you notice `"http://syndex.me/tagged/"+formElm.q.value`. `formElm.q` refers to an input element called `q` within the form element. `formElem.q.value` holds the value of the input element, which contains the search keywords. The just constructed URL is assigned to `window.location`, which initiates a new request to `http://syndex.me/tagged/`*search_terms*.
  After that line, you see `return false`. Inside the `onsubmit` event handler, you've seen `return handleThis(this)`. The return value of `handleThis` is passed to the `onsubmit` event handler. So, the statement equals `onsubmit="return false"`. This means that the form does not submit itself any more.
- The **action** attribute is **not defined**. As mentioned previously, this is not needed, because the form is not submitted due `return false`. When an error occurs, or if a user has disabled JavaScript, the form will submit itself to the URL as defined at `action`. Because the `action` attribute is not specified, the page's current URL is used instead, `http://syndex.me/` in this case. All named form elements are added to the request, so the final URL will be `http://syndex.me/?q=`*search_terms*

To get back to your question, `<form action="/tagged"`method="get">`:

- **No `onsubmit`** event handler.
- Because the `onsubmit` event handler is not specified, the HTML form will be **submitted by the browser** (an imaginary `onsubmit` handler would equal `return true`.
- The **action** URL is **defined** to be **`/tagged`**, which translates to *a file called "tagged" at the ROOT directory of your host*. In this case: `http://syndex.me/tagged?q=`*search_terms*. (`q=..` is a result from the input element called `q`).
  When you change `action` to `/tagged/` instead of `/tagged`, the submitted form will request the following page: `http://syndex.me/tagged/?q=`*search_terms*

When you change `/tagged` to `/search`, your form submits to `http://syndex.me/search?q=...`. As seen through the headers, this location redirects to `http://syndex.me/search/...`.
This behaviour is likely achieved using a rule defined in [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/search\?q=(.*)$ /search/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Understood?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that so well, it's sincerely appreciated.