# Open multiple Bowser Tabs with Submit Button

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I am using this script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622181/open-a-url-based-on-search-query-without-php-q-myterm-and-instead-with-a-si/7622800#7622800)! to open a search query on Amazon in a new window/tab.

Now I like to use the form to open multiple tabs (tab 1: search query for Amazon, tab 2: search query for Ebay etc.) and I am facing the problem Chrome does not open multiple tabs with the JS "window.open". This seems to be because of the popup blocker.

But now I found a website where they where able to open multiple tabs using a submit button: swoodoo. 
If the user fills in the form some checkboxes for other websites appearing and if the are active the searchquery opens more the one tab with the same search query.

Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/ZE00uoE0CFOy

Any idea how they made this?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass`_blank` as the second parameter to `window.open` the page will open in a new tab.

```
window.open('http://www.amazon.com', '_blank');
```

Comment: yes true but I am looking for a solution with multiple tab not just one.